# What is the thing on the left side of a sum mean?

Tags: game-theory

To be more specific:

What is the thing on the left side of a sum mean?

[image]

Comment: $1$ divided by the absolute value of $N.$

Comment: Well, if $N$ is a finite set then $|N|$ denotes the number of elements in $N$.

Answer (score 2):

So, $|N|$ means the number of elements in $N$. And if we write in for example
$$
c\sum_i a_i x^i,
$$
what we mean is
$$
c\cdot \left(\sum_i a_i x^i\right).
$$
That is to say, "stuff on the left side of a sum" is not connected to the sum at all; we just multiply the whole sum by it.

(^ Some of that might be obvious to you; in that case don't take it as patronising or anything, I just don't know where you're coming from.)

Comment: I'm disappointed how painfully obvious that was...

Comment: @Tryingmybest Haha, don't feel bad - happens to the best of us!